# Save transient field in Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, moshi

Consider the following data model where `status` is provided by the API at the top level and `message` is provided at a nested level (this isn't really the case but just to illustrate the problem):

```
data class (
    @Json(name = "status")
    val status: Int,

    @Transient
    val message: String
)
```

Now, suppose I want to save this data model into my database. I'd change the model like so:

```
data class (
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    @Json(name = "status")
    val status: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
    @Transient
    val message: String
)
```

the `message` field will not be saved into the database due to the `Transient` annotation. But what if I want to? How can I force Room to save the field but `Moshi` to ignore it.

The problem is I have no control over this API, or how it would change in the future, so removing `@Transient` and changing the name to some random complicated string is not an ideal solution, even if it will fix the problem.

---

Found a couple of related issues on [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi):

- [Moshi/94](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/94)
- [Moshi/1262](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1262)

Apparently this is an age-old issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, can you use a mapper between your object and Room database ?

Like:

```kotlin
data class MessageEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    val status: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
    val message: String
) {
// ... 
}
```

```kotlin
data class Message (
    @Json(name = "status")
    val status: Int,

    @Transient
    val message: String
) {
 fun toEntity(): MessageEntity {// ...}
 fun fromEntity(e: MessageEntity): Message {// ...} // or Extensions
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did consider this but I am very hesitant to do this, you see I already have somewhere around 200-300 data classes, and I'd have to do this in about 34 of them. So, I'm looking for a solution with minimal changes required. Not only that but, these data classes are already integrated into the code and I'd have to refactor them as well. Such a nightmare! :-)

Comment: Another way maybe, you can use a [Moshi custom adapter](https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-type-adapters). Have you tried this already ? It might be "cleaner".

Comment: The reason for `message` existence *is* a custom adapter which reads nested data blocks and moves it to the top. But that is the issue you see, the type adapter creates a field at the entity level, thus by forcing me to the use of `Transient` annotation for the safe exclusion from the API response parsing. I wanted to explain this and the above in the OP but that inflated the question itself so I ended up removing all that in favor of brevity and to keep the question non-specific (sigh). Maybe I should've kept it!

Comment: I see your point and yes your original answer is how it should be implemented but like I said it's a little impactful. I might end up doing just that in which case I'd accept your answer, but I'd rather not resort to that final solution any time soon or without effort to look for a different/easier solution!